# Can i setState of a react functional component from a external gloabal function present inside script tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an android app which calls the a function present inside the head of my react
page. All i want is to allow the the function to set a state inside the react component

```
<head>
  <script>
    webViewAndriodInteraction(parm1)
    {
      //Here i want this function to change the state of my react functional component
      //setSomeState(pram)
    }
  </script>
</head>;

function LiveScreen(props) {
  const [somedata, setSomeState] = useState();
  return <h1>someData</h1>;
}
```

Comment: yes if you pass `setSomeState` function as a parameter of the function

Comment: how can i  pass setSomeState as the perimeter of the function as it is being called from android side. and it does not have access to setSomeState function

Answer (score 0):

It's probably against some React best practices, but you could do this:

In your component, define an effect that puts your state setter on the `window` object:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.setSomeState = setSomeState;

  return () => {
    window.setSomeState = undefined;
  };
}, []);
```

And in your `webViewAndriodInteraction` function:

```
if (window.setSomeState !== undefined) {
  // call window.setSomeState here
}
```

You also need to ensure that your call to `window.setSomeState` is deferred until the function gets defined. So if you're sure it's going to get defined, you could set a timeout or retry the `if` check a few times with a given delay.